# Which operations are easier to implement in pull vs push models in streaming libraries (and vice versa)?

Tags: scala, reactive-streams, fs2, monix

Author of Monix says in [comparison of Monix with FS2](https://monix.io/docs/2x/reactive/observable-comparisons.html#fs2-the-new-scalaz-stream)

> Where FS2 is better:
>
> - the model of communication between producers and consumers is pull-based, sometimes making it easier to implement new operators
>
> Where Monix is better:
>
> - the model of communication between producers and consumers is push-based (with back-pressure) and this makes it inherently more efficient

Few questions arise:

- Which operations are easier to implement in pull-based model?
- Are there operations which are *harder* to implement this way?
- Why pull-based approach is inherently slower?

Comment: One operation that is easier to implement with a pull-based approach is `zip`. If there is two streams that you want to zip together, the pull-based approach just asks for the next element of the two streams and returns the tuple to the consumer. A push-based approach has to buffer elements if the streams are coming in at different rates, potentially causing memory issues or data loss.

Comment: Usually though, the two approaches are used for different problems at hand. Pull-based approaches shine when it comes to lazy data transformation, while push-based approaches work well with listeners and event handlers, so for example when building front-end-applications. With pull-based approaches ontop of event-based systems what you will end up doing is polling the data source over and over for changes, which wastes computing energy on nothing.

Comment: I don't think pull-based approaches are *slower*, they are just less *efficient*. Given the right circumstances they are as fast as push-based approaches, I think.